# Looping through Merged cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to loop through merged cells in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

- I have 6 merged cells in the range `B4:B40`
- I need the values in these 6 cells 6 iterations only.

Comment: do you know how many cells are merged? why do you want only 6 iterations? could you explain us a little more what you **intend to do**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The above answers look to have you sorted.

If you don't know where the merged cells are then you can use the following routine to quickly detect them.

When I built [Mappit!](http://sdrv.ms/18pQI6C) I realised that when I developed merged cell reporting that merged cells were part of `xlBlanks`

So you can use the code to detect merged cells immediately rather than loop through each cell testing for the `MergedCells` property being true.

```
Sub DetectMerged()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Intersect(Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas), Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks))
Set rng2 = Intersect(Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants), Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks))
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Merged formulae cells in " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Merged constant cells in " & rng2.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a first stab to your issue:

```
Option Explicit

Sub loopOverCells()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rCell = [B1]
    For i = 1 To 6
        Debug.Print rCell.Address
        Set rCell = rCell.Offset(1, 0)    ' Jump 1 row down to the next cell
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that to understand better how `Offset()` works it might be more precise to say that it jumps to the next item of grouped cells instead of saying that Jumps 1 row down to the next cell. What do you think JMax?

Answer (score 2):

Just a little tighter, similar idea:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListValues()
Dim i As Long

    For i = 4 To 40 Step 6
        Debug.Print Range("B" & i).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an iterative sub given a range with merged cells

```
Sub IterateMerged(ByVal r As Range)

    ' You can switch these loops to iterate through rows first 
    Dim CurrentRow as Double
    Dim CurrentCol as Double
    For CurrentRow = 0 To r.Rows.Count Step 0
        For CurrentCol = 0 to r.Columns.Count Step 0

            ' You could additionally add a if statement to check if this cell is merged, to iterate only over merged cells
            ' Your code goes here
            MsgBox "I'm at: " & r.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).MergeArea.Address

            CurrentCol = CurrentCol + r.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).MergeArea.Columns.Count
        Next CurrentCol
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + r.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).MergeArea.Rows.Count
    Next CurrentRow

End Sub
```