# Working with merge and center cells in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

If I take a range over merge and centered cells in excel, are each of them addressed as single cells or the group of cells constituting them? For example, if the cells A1 to A10 are merged and I do a

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A5")
```

Would this return the range of a single cell among those constituting the merged cell or a range consisting the merged cell itself? And what value would it contain if I get its value?

In other words, how would you represent range over merged cells in excel VBA?

Also, how can I get the range of the non merged cells adjacent to the length of this merged cell?

Comment: `In other words, how would you represent range over merged cells in excel VBA?` By addressing it with the top left cell. Ex: "A1" in this case.

Comment: That means that every merged cell would be addressed by the first cell constituting it?

Comment: Yup :) Try `Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Value = "Blah Blah"` and then `Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Blah Blah"`

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, how would you represent range over merged cells in excel VBA?

By addressing it with the top left cell. Ex: "A1" in this case.

When in doubt, check it yourself first. If still in doubt, search google or whatever search engine you use. Still if something is unclear, ask :)

> Would this return the range of a single cell among those constituting the merged cell or a range consisting the merged cell itself? And what value would it contain if I get its value?

It would return a single cell `A5` which doesn't have anything in it because when you merge cells the data from the top left cell is kept and rest discarded. The reason why I say discarded is that if you now unmerge the cells, you will not get your values back.

**Best way to check**:

Let's say `A1` to `A10` had `1,2,3..10`. Merge them. The cell will now have only `1`

Try this in Immediate window

`?Range("A5").Value`

You will get nothing. Similarly if you want to write to it, you cannot use `Range("A5").Value = "Blah"`. You have to address it with the top left cell. For example

`Range("A1").Value = "Blah"`

Comment: So, if I have a range over column A and it consists of merged cells and I do a `For Each cell` over that range, would it address the cells that are within the merged region or would it skip to the next cell outside this region?

Comment: it will address the cells within the merged region. Give it a try and debug.print the address of each cell.

Comment: You may follow the advice at the top of this answer. That will surely answer this and many other questions.

Comment: @sancho.s: I was exactly typing that in my edit :D a different variation though but meant the same thing :)

Comment: Then how would I know whether a cell belongs to a merged region or not?

Comment: `Range("A5").MergeArea.Address` will give you the complete address of the merged area

Comment: [Found via Google](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14599841/2707864), searching for "vba how to know if a cell belongs to a merged range". These questions show extremely poor efforts. You probably had to type in Google instead of in a comment.

Comment: @sancho.s: I agree about the poor research efforts by OP but the link that you gave doesn't give you the complete address of the merged area. See my last comment.

Comment: That is correct. It is only about "whether a cell belongs to a merged region or not". Your comment deals with the complete address of the merged area.