# Loop through cells/merged cells in column

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to Excel VBA and haven't quite familiarized myself with all the different functions. This is what I would like to have happen:

I have a column containing value in combination of cells and **merged cells**. I have to perform an action in **for** **loop** for that column. I want the loop to move from 1 cell to next and not based on the row. e.g cell C1 is merged cell (C1-C3) so the loop should next go to C4 rather than C2.
In the attached image, I want the loop to go like C1 -> C4 -> C5 -> C7 -> C11 and like that..

[image]

Comment: share the code your tried so far

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391428/7889129 by JMax. it will solve your problem

Comment: JMax's solution looks at identifying merged cells rather than looping through cells in a range, and only the first cell if a sub range is merged, so OP would need additional logic to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: My sample data is on **Sheet1** (merged cells are outlined)

[image: sample data]

The code: in **Sheet1 module**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SkipMerged()

    Dim colA As Range, itm As Range

    Set colA = Me.UsedRange.Columns(1)

    Set itm = colA.Cells(1)

    While Len(itm.Value2) > 0

        Debug.Print "Merged area: " & itm.MergeArea.Address(0, 0)

        Set itm = itm.MergeArea.Offset(1)

    Wend

End Sub
```

---

The output in the Immediate Window:

```
Merged area: A1:A3
Merged area: A4
Merged area: A5:A6
Merged area: A7:A9
```

Comment: My goodness. How simple and smart but still does loop through all doesn't it?  Or does looping through 2 cells that are merged really mean looping through one?

Comment: @QHarr - Good point. The latest version only loops through merged cells