# Getting rid of Merged cells With Center across selection

Tags: vba, merge

Hello Recently someone posted this in a comment thread in one of my previous questions. The post itself shows a code to remove merged cells and replace them with Central Across Selection

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197726/getting-rid-of-merged-cells/197730#197730

My issue is that I can't seem to get the code to work. I tried giving the code a go but am having two issues with it. Primarily the:

```
Sub fixMergedCells(sh As Worksheet)
```

and later

```
Set used = sh.UsedRange
```

Which I don't quite understand and they seem to be stopping me from applying it as a macro button. I otherwise seem to get a debug prompt saying "Method 'UnMerge' of object 'Range' failed" with regards to the line:

```
 .UnMerge
```

Could you give me a hand in understanding what it is that I can't seem to grasp.

Here is my original code from my other post:

```
Sub fixMergedCells(sh As Worksheet)
'replace merged cells by Center Acroos Selection
'high perf version using a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452164/78522
    Dim c As Range, used As Range
    Dim m As Range, i As Long
    Dim constFla: constFla = Array(xlConstants, xlFormulas)

    Set used = sh.UsedRange
    For i = 0 To 1  '1 run for constants, 1 for formulas
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Set m = Intersect(used.Cells.SpecialCells(constFla(i)), used.Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not m Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In m.Cells
                If c.MergeCells Then
                    With c.MergeArea
                        'Debug.Print .Address
                        .UnMerge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub test_fixMergedCells()
    fixMergedCells ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you place the fixMergedCells sub procedure in a worksheet's private code sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Your sub procedure isn't listed in the available 'macros' because it has a non-optional, non-variant parameter.

Try using an optional variant type parameter that can be used or, if omitted, filled with the ActiveSheet (which I assume the button is on).

```
Sub fixMergedCells(Optional sh As Variant)

    If IsMissing(sh) Then Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.Cells.UnMerge

End Sub
```

IsMissing can only be used with optional variant type parameters. Sub procedures with optional parameters are only listed as available 'macros' to be assigned to a button if the optional parameter is the variant type.