# Loop though merged cells and border "down"

Tags: excel, vba

These are my merged cells

[image]

I would like to loop though these merged cells, find the end of every merged cell and then **Border Around on the left with Dots(xlDots)** till **ROW6**

This would be my output

[image]

Here is what I tried until now

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:I6")

With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlDot
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

But it borders me every cell, can I give a **STEP 2** like in a for loop?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I won't discuss with you why you downvote because I didn't really read all that stuff, I think that peolple can just "Say it before downvote" that there is someting that is not working in that question. But I only asked a simple and clean question, like @MilesFett asked "Can you show us what you've tried so far?" and I did it, my code is wrong but I still did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is based of a trick seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452164/9758194)

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
With Sheet1 'Change appropriately
    Set rng = Intersect(.Cells.SpecialCells(2), .Cells.SpecialCells(4))
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.MergeArea.Row = 3 Then
            cl.MergeArea.Offset(1).Resize(3, cl.MergeArea.Columns.Count).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDot
        End If
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

- [`.Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) creates a range out of all cells that are part of merged areas through the use of [`.SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). I used a combination of [constants and blanks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype) (indexes 2 and 4 respectively) but if your values are a result of formulas you can change that to -4123 and 4.
- I made sure these cells are part of a [`.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) that starts at row 3.
- Then simply [`.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) by 1 row and [`.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) that range object up to row 6 and the actual width of the merged area (using Columns.Count) since you might not be 100% sure about the width of columns of these merged areas.
- You can set the  `xlEdgeLeft` border's linestyle right there to `xlDot`.

---

Obviously, if your range of merged cells only involves column A-I it would get a lot more simple, while this solution is a bit more dynamic in that sense.

Comment: I knew it that you would answer! Always perfect eh! jvdV your are the MASTER!

Comment: Ha, definately not the master and perfect. Just enjoying solving problems. Glad this solved yours. Enjoy. =)

Answer (score 3):

Here is variation on @JvdV answer.

```
For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:M3") 'change sheet as needed
    If cel.MergeCells = True Then
        With cel.MergeArea.Offset(1).Resize(3).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlDash
        End With
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: In fact @ChangeWorld, if you always only interested in `Range("A3:M3")`, this might be a faster routine.

Comment: @Gmalc, you might want to consider to specify your worksheet too, otherwise shorter routine than mine +1 :)

Comment: @JvdV, usually do, but just wanted to show the variation I was playing with, I was happy to notice we were on the same track.

Comment: Updated per @JvdV suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you don't need VBA. You can use Conditional Formatting:

Rule:

```
=AND(A$3<>"",B$3="",C$3="")
```

Applies to Range:

```
=$C$4:$I$6
```

And of course just choose the format as desired.

Comment: Upvoted to avoid VBA, but I'm not sure these merged cells would always be just 3 wide as OP mentioned: `" find the end of every merged cell "`

Comment: Yeah I achived it though Conditional Formatting, but I would like to learn it though VBA since I'm making **Macros**