# How to import excel worksheet with many merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code (below) that allows users to upload a worksheet. However, the worksheet can at times have many merged cells. This takes the upload process 5-6 mins to complete. Anyway to speed up the upload using VBA?
Also, the merged cells are blanks so it is OK to ignore them.

```
Sub Upload()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File         
& Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
Set src = OpenBook.Sheets(1)
src.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear from your posted code why having merged cells would make any difference in performance.  It really take 5-6mins to copy a single sheet?

Comment: hi @TimWilliams, to add, the worksheet that I'm trying to upload has 1500 rows of which 50% are horizontally merged cells. There are 6 columns in all.

Comment: 1500 rows would not account for 5-6mins to copy the sheet.

Comment: Yes, which is why I think it is the 750 merged cells that is resulting in 5-6 mins load time

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to change merged cells into 'center across selection' cells:

```
Sub fixMergedCells(sh As Worksheet)
'replace merged cells by Center Across Selection
'superfast version using a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452164/78522
    Dim c As Range, used As Range
    Dim m As Range, i As Long
    Dim constFla: constFla = Array(xlConstants, xlFormulas)
    
    Set used = sh.UsedRange
    For i = 0 To 1                               '1 run for constants, 1 for formulas
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Set m = Intersect(used.Cells.SpecialCells(constFla(i)), used.Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not m Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In m.Cells
                If c.MergeCells Then
                    With c.MergeArea
                        'Debug.Print .Address
                        .UnMerge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```