# Select all visable sheets and cells, unmerge cells and fill down

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks with a varying number and names for sheets. The sheets have a number of merged cells that i need to unmerge and then copy the cell data. I've been unsuccessfully trying to blend a few different scripts together. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to write a VB script that will do the following

1. Select all visible sheets in the workbook
2. Select all cells with data
3. Unmerge any merged cells
4. copy values down

```
         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
               
Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next

         Next I
```

Comment: And what exactly is your issue? Any errors? What's wrong? And What is your question? See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). • This might help: [Looping through Merged cells in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391092/looping-through-merged-cells-in-vba)

Comment: I have the impression you are trying to write a VBA macro from scratch, which is great. However, it is also possible to record one and you might learn from there what might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've been unsuccessful at get a recorded macro to work.  I've been able to walk through
          Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count 

This part works and selects all sheets , but the second part should also run on each sheet. That marco works by it's self but not when nested within the other. When i run it, it hangs and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

My ultimate solution was going to be in power Bi and i found out you can use the fill function to copy the merge cell data without having to mess with excel at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).